# Import dll into oracle 11g database

Tags: oracle11g

How to import dll into oracle 11g database? Is it possible? If possible, how to call the dll? Can anyone give me some examples? I can't find a proper solution online and I hope there is a way to do this.

Comment: It really isn't clear what you're trying to do. I'm not sure what 'import a DLL into the database' means. You want a client program to access the DLL (in which case just link the client to it); or some code in the database to access it - if so why, and what would it be doing?

Comment: add library into database and use it externally by calling a procedure..